# Django smart_str 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

In django, I want to download the data to excel using the smart_str, but some record of user dont have data or blank some field like in the error below, how can i do with smart_str which should be unnecessary or error free if no data can be detected?

```
def downloadcv(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    # decide the file name
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="StudentEnrollmentRecord.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response, csv.excel)
    response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))
    writer.writerow([
       smart_str(u"Guardians_Fullname"),
       smart_str(u"Guardians_Address"),
       smart_str(u"Contact_Number"),
    ])
    reports = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.filter(School_Year=yearid).order_by('Education_Levels','-Date_Time')
    for report in reports:
        last_name = report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_LastName or ""
        first_name = report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_FirstName or ""
        initial = report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_Middle_Initial or ""
        writer.writerow([
        smart_str(last_name, first_name, initial),
    return response if response is not None else 'None'
```

this is the error i get

[image]

Comment: This means that `report.Student_Users.Parent_Users` is `None`.

Comment: yes, exactly, ybut i still need to download it to excel

Comment: that is why I have or None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a [try-catch exception handler](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Give this a try

```
try:
   last_name = report.Student_Users.Parent_Users.Guardian_LastName
except AttributeError:
   last_name = ""
```

*NB: You may have to do the same for the rest of fields also*